# Naming Image using index of for loop in each iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop, image-processing, matrix

I am working in MATLAB for my image processing project. 
I am using a for loop to generate some kind of image data (size of image varies) with each loop iteration. My problem is how do stop it from overwriting the image in next iteration.

```
Img(i,j)=data
```

Ideally I would like it to have

```
Img_1 = data (for 1st iteration)
Img_2 = data (for 2nd iteration)
Img_3 = data (for 3rd iteration)
```

and so on...

Is there any way, it can be acheived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [dynamic field names with structures](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/).  I wouldn't recommend using separate variable names because your workspace will become unwieldy.  Do something like this:

```
img_struct = struct(); %// Create empty structure

for ii = 1 : num_iterations
    %// Do your processing on data
    %...
    %...

    img_struct.(['Img_' num2str(ii)]) = data; %// After iteration
end
```

This will create a structure called `img_struct` where it will have fields that are named `Img_1`, `Img_2`, etc.  To access a particular data from an iteration... say... iteration 1, do:

```
data = img_struct.Img_1;
```

Change the `_1` to whatever iteration you choose.

---

Alternatively, you can use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)... same line of thinking:

```
%// Create empty cell array
img_cell = cell(num_iterations, 1);

for ii = 1 : num_iterations
    %// Do your processing on data
    %...
    %...

    img_cell{ii} = data; %// After iteration
end
```

Cell arrays are arrays that take on any type per element - or they're non-homogeneous arrays.  This means that each element can be whatever you want.  As such, because your image data varies in size at each iteration, this will do very nicely.   To access data at any iteration, simply do:

```
data = img_cell{ii};
```

`ii` is the index of the iteration you want to access.

Comment: Thanks. BTW out of sturct and cell, which is more efficient?

Comment: @user11659 - It totally depends on your preference.  There are functions that you can apply to each to get what you want.  Structures are nice because you have actual variable names associated to your data, but you need to specify the full name of each to get what you want.  Cells are easy because you just have to specify an **index** to the variable you want, but if you wanted to assign a meaningful name to each variable, you can't.  That being said, it just depends on what you're comfortable with.  Neither of them are efficient/inefficient in terms of accessing data. BTW, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to literally obtain what you are asking for, you can use the `eval()` function, which takes a string as input that it will evaluate as if it were a line of code. Example:

```
for i=1:3
data=ones(i); % assign data, 'ones(i)' used as dummy for test
eval(['Img_' num2str(i) '=data;'])
end
```

However, I would recommend using cell arrays `{}`, or alternatively the `struct` function that rayryeng both suggested.

Comment: I normally downvote `eval` answers because it's bad code, but because you mentioned that this isn't a recommended and that cell arrays or `struct`s are better, you have my upvote.